# Filtering out array of object and do maths for specific element

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

I've an array of object. Let's say

```
let cartItems = [
   {title: "Veg Salad", category: {title: "Salad"}, quantity: 2, price: 30},
   {title: "Roti", category: {title: "Breads"}, quantity: 3, price: 10},
   {title: "Biriyani", category: {title: "Biriyani"}, quantity: 2, price: 100},
   {title: "Veg Curry", category: {title: "Curry"}, quantity: 3, price: 60},
]
```

Here there is no packing charge for ***category - Salad and Breads*** but 20 Rupee packing charge for ***Category - Biriyani and Curry***. So I want to filter out rest of the array objects and increment 20 Rupee per quantity and want total packing charge.

```
const findPackCharge = cartItems.filter((ele) => {
  return (
    ele.category?.title != "Salad" && ele.category?.title != "Breads"
  );
});

console.log(findPackCharge, "FIND");
```

I tried alot but not able to figure it out.

Comment: there is no packing charge in any of 4 objects.

Comment: @Shubanker It's clearly mentioned there, no packing charge for Category Salad and Breads, and 20 Rupee Packing charge for Category Biriyani and Curry

Comment: Loop over the filtered array, and calculate the total of `20 * ele.quantity`

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you want to do but if it's just about getting only the total packing charge, just multiply 20 by the each item quanity and save it's sum.

```js
const cartItems = [
   {title: "Veg Salad", category: {title: "Salad"}, quantity: 2, price: 30},
   {title: "Roti", category: {title: "Breads"}, quantity: 3, price: 10},
   {title: "Biriyani", category: {title: "Biriyani"}, quantity: 2, price: 100},
   {title: "Veg Curry", category: {title: "Curry"}, quantity: 3, price: 60},
]

const NO_PACKING_CHARGE_ITEMS = ["Breads", "Salad"];
const totalPackingCharge = cartItems.reduce((accu, item) => {
  const isNoPackingChargeItem = NO_PACKING_CHARGE_ITEMS.includes(item.category.title);
  return isNoPackingChargeItem ? accu + (item.quantity * 20) : accu;
}, 0);
console.log(totalPackingCharge);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `reduce()` to calculate the total packing charge. In the callback function you can skip the items that have no charge.

```js
let cartItems = [
   {title: "Veg Salad", category: {title: "Salad"}, quantity: 2, price: 30},
   {title: "Roti", category: {title: "Breads"}, quantity: 3, price: 10},
   {title: "Biriyani", category: {title: "Biriyani"}, quantity: 2, price: 100},
   {title: "Veg Curry", category: {title: "Curry"}, quantity: 3, price: 60},
];

const findPackCharge = cartItems.reduce((total, ele) => {
  if (ele.category?.title != "Salad" && ele.category?.title != "Breads") {
    total += 20 * ele.quantity;
  }
  return total;
}, 0);

console.log(findPackCharge, "FIND");
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const cartItems = [
    { title: "Veg Salad", category: { title: "Salad" }, quantity: 2,  price: 30 },
    { title: "Roti", category: { title: "Breads" }, quantity: 3, price: 10 },
    { title: "Biriyani", category: { title: "Biriyani" }, quantity: 2, price: 100 },
    { title: "Veg Curry", category: { title: "Curry" }, quantity: 3, price: 60 }
];

const packingFee = 20;
const noPackingItems = ["Breads", "Salad"];
const findPackCharge = cartItems.filter((ele) =>         
    !noPackingItems.includes(ele.category?.title)
  ).reduce((total, e) => total + e.quantity * packingFee, 0) ;

console.log(findPackCharge, "for packing charge");
```